# Mediasoup - MediaTrack.applyConstrains working not well after using that track created a producer by mediasoup-client api

Tags: javascript, webrtc

The case is, I want to change the video resolution after created a producer like this

```
videoProducer.track.applyConstraints({
    width: { ideal:1280 },
    height: { ideal: 960 }
}).then(()=> {
    console.log("success")
})
```

After success, I have checked video tag videoHeight and videoWidth properties, it showed 640*480. But, if I close the video producer using `videoProducer.close()`, it becomes 1280 * 960, I don't know how to cause it.

So, it needs close producer first when I want to change any constraints, is there a more graceful solution?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "mediasoup-api", and I don't see a tag for it. What's a `videoProducer`? Is this a local track from a camera, or a remote track from peer connection?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Mediasoup is an SFU server, I have used it to build my WebRTC app. [Mediasoup document](https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v2/mediasoup-client/api/#Producer) may have some useful information.

Comment: Is this a local track from a camera, or a remote track from peer connection?

Comment: Local track. Fetch by myself but have handled by the producer of mediasoup's API.

Comment: If it's a local track that should work, but you should be able to test that without mediasoup. You can also try s/`ideal`/`exact`/, as well as with higher values to see if it fails. And different browsers. All to isolate the problem.

Comment: The problem is, it worked well if I have closed video producer. It may be an issue for  `mediasoup-client`. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is that using mediasoup v2 or v3? Also, the mediasoup support forum is here: https://mediasoup.discourse.group.